# SQL Date format not changing

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to do a simple date format change.

My query looks like this:

```
select to_date('01-JAN-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual.
```

This is part of a much bigger query.

This is giving error like below on my prod:

```
oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

This exact same is working fine on my offline oracle 10g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `to_date()`.  Instead use the `date` keyword:

```
select date '2018-01-01'
```

Alternatively, use the right format:

```
select to_date('01-JAN-2018', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
from dual
```

Comment: The issue is that my month is coming from parameters, and it is always a 3 letter month like 'JAN','FEB',..... And in this too if i write : select date '2018-JAN-01' from dual, it gives error that 'invalid month'

Comment: @Fumble Bit, it appears that you didn't notice that Gordon said that you should use the **correct** format mask - if your data is JAN, FEB, then use "MON". If it is 01, 02, then use "MM".

Answer (score 1):

There's a mismatch with formatting `mm` and `MON`.

Use

`select to_date('01-JAN-2018','dd-MON-yyyy') from dual`

or

```
select to_date('01-01-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual
```

In your oracle 10g db, `nls_date_format` must be `dd-mm-yyyy` ( or variants like `dd.mm.yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`).

So, it doesn't care of `dd-mon-yyyy`(i.e. implicitly converts `dd-MON-yyyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy`)

Comment: yes but i only have a query interface. I cannot change `nls_date_format` using `alter session` on my prod

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    select to_date('01-01-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual
```